# Join multiple dataframes in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, left-join, foldleft

I have two variables. One is a Dataframe and other is a List[Dataframe]. I wish to perform a join on these. At the moment I am using the following appoach:

```
def joinDfList(SingleDataFrame: DataFrame, DataFrameList: List[DataFrame], groupByCols: List[String]): DataFrame = {

    var joinedDf = SingleDataFrame
    DataFrameList.foreach(
      Df => {
        joinedDf = joinedDf.join(Df, groupByCols, "left_outer")
      }
    )
    joinedDf.na.fill(0.0)
}
```

Is there an approach where we can skip usage of "var" and instead of "foreach" use "foldleft"?

Comment: There is, but why don't you try it yourself first? `foldLeft` operates on a list and takes one dataframe to get the ball rolling and a function that produces another dataframe from 2 dataframes. You have all of those things right there.

Comment: Also, variable names should start with lowercase characters, since it makes it easier to distinguish them from types (and singleton `object`s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple write it without vars using `foldLeft`:

```
def joinDfList(singleDataFrame: DataFrame, dataFrameList: List[DataFrame], groupByCols: List[String]): DataFrame = 
  dataFrameList.foldLeft(singleDataFrame)(
    (dfAcc, nextDF) => dfAcc.join(nextDF, groupByCols, "left_outer")
  ).na.fill(0.0)
```

in this code `dfAcc` will be always join with new `DataFrame` from `dataFrameList` and in the end you will get one `DataFrame`

**Important!** be careful, using too many joins in one job might be a reason of performance degradation.

Comment: Why do we use a case here? @Boris

Comment: @Keshvi Srivastava it is not obligatory here